# Aspx change causing a reload?

Tags: asp.net-1.1

We have a setup here that is less than ideal, We have our webserver configured so that there is a global application and then we have each web applications dll ( hundreds ) in WEBROOT/bin

Recently I made a change to a ASPX page in .NET 1.1. and we I went to check the change it was complaining that a seperate and totally unconnected DLL was not being loaded. I am not understanding how the ASPX file change would cause all the DLLs to get reloaded.

I removed the offending DLL and the problem went away.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing an .aspx page causes a recompile of all the .aspx files in the same directory, which is why the dll is getting reloaded.  You'd be much better off if you could split things up into separate applications in IIS.  If that's not possible I'm not sure how you could get around this...

Comment: I don't have the cs files on the server, so is it true just for the ASPX files, that it would recompile them??

Comment: The aspx file is compiled at runtine into a class derived from the cs file. The cs file is already compiled into a dll.